# Python split words before ':' character but not time structure

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to `Split` words before `:` character using regex.

However, I don't want to `split` time structure, like 15:46:00 hrs.

All the information I have is inside a `for` loop, and comes from scraping a pdf file.

so, using this code:

```
for item in result:
    for key in keyHeaders:
        if key in item.encode('utf-8'):
            item = item.replace(key, '')
    if ':' in item:
        item = item.replace(':', ':\n')
```

Output:

```
15:
46:
00
State:
NY
Phone:
x-xxx-xxx
```

Using regex or non-regex how can I `split` specifically words but not numbers joined by `:` character.

I tried this, but nothing happen. In fact, it doesn´t split anything.

```
for item in result:
    for key in keyHeaders:
        if key in item.encode('utf-8'):
            item = item.replace(key, '')
    lines = re.compile(r'(?<!\\d\\d):(?!\\d\\d)') # expect split words before ':'
    if item == re.findall(lines, item):
        item = item.replace(':', ':\n')
```

output:

```
15:46:00
State:NY
Phone:x-xxx-xxx
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: What does your original input look like? Is it just `"15:46:00 State:NY Phone:x-xxx-xxx"`?

Comment: Not, there are several items, like 100. And they change depending on content from pdf. However, almost 100% of the words are before a `:` character.

Comment: That's what makes me think `regex` could be a good option to `split` them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues with your code.  First you used a raw string and then still doubled the backslashes on '\\d', change those to '\d'.  The other issue is that your comparing the entire item with the value returned by re.findall.  If your regexp were correct, re.findall would have returned only a ':' for the items that are not dates, so you should either compare with ':' or just that anything is returned.

Your regexp is also overly complex for a relatively simple match.  I would use something like:

```
if not re.findall(r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d', item):
    item = item.replace(':', ':\n')
```

There are also likely simpler ways to do the whole job with re.sub or re.split, but this should get you over your current hurdle.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for your help. It prints just the output I was looking for. Gracias.